# TinyMCE is not showing some toolbar elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to use the latest TinyMCE in my project (the project uses jQuery 3 if that matters), and my problem is that if I initialize the textarea like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#idOfTextarea',
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | copy paste undo redo | removeformat'
});
```

Then bullist, numlist, and link is missing. There are no errors on the console output, and the other buttons are working well. If I look at source, they don't even have a placeholder.[image: icons not showing up]

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is there a solution?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the initialisation code as below :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#idOfTextarea',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link "
    ],
    toolbar: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | copy paste undo redo | removeformat'
});
```

To use bullist, numlist, and link, you've to add plugins

Comment: In the getting started guide, this was not mentioned. Thank you! :)

Comment: glad..it helps :)